# Matlab crashes after attempt to use custom performance function for NN toolsbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Recently I've tried to use a custom performance function for NN in Matlab. What I did as an initial experiment, I took **mse** template and copy these files to my Matlab working directory. After that I renamed **+mse** folder and **mse.m** to **mymse.m**, leaving everything else(the code inside) unchanged. After that when I attempt to run NN tools with this new custom function(which is actually fully equal to the old one), Matlab randomly crashes.

And I don't mean exceptions. I mean Access Violation errors that kill Matlab instance.

When Matlab does not crash, it gives normal results.

Has anyone come across this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If it only chrases some times then it may be a bug. Contact Mathworks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the parent folder which +name folder is in. 
Even if that parent folder is your current folder, it does not mean that it is included. 
So, rigth click to the parent folder, and 'add to path'. This may be one of the reason that it crashes. 
also, another thing that you have to keep in mind: 
 when trainin with custom performance functions, you may need to use train(net,x,t,nn7) instead of train(net,x,t) or you may get just zeros for output.